# Docker run on sub domains

Tags: apache, http, ubuntu, nginx, docker

My goal is to deploy multiple webapps and access them through sub-domains, I'm currently running them on different ports, I have nginx on the server and the containers are running apache.

```
docker run -p 8001:80 -d apache-test1
docker run -p 8002:80 -d apache-test2
```

and I'm able to access them by going to

```
http://example.com:8001
```

or
    http://example.com:8002

But I like to access them through sub-domains instead

```
http://example.com:8001 -> http://test1.example.com
http://example.com:8002 -> http://test2.example.com
```

I have nginx running on the server with the following server settings

```
server {
    server_name test1.anomamedia.com;
    location / {
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host ;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr ;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for ;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8001;
    }
}

server {
    server_name test2.anomamedia.com;
    location / {
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host ;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr ;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for ;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8002;
    }
}
```

If its of any help this is my Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y upgrade

RUN sudo apt-get -y install apache2 php5 libapache2-mod-php5

# Install apache, PHP, and supplimentary programs. curl and lynx-cur are for debugging the container.
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install apache2 libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mysql php5-gd php-pear php-apc php5-curl curl lynx-cur

# Enable apache mods.
RUN a2enmod php5
RUN a2enmod rewrite

EXPOSE 80

# Copy site into place.
ADD html /var/www/html

# Update the default apache site with the config we created.
ADD apache-config.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

# By default, simply start apache.
CMD /usr/sbin/apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND
```

Comment: and what's the question actually?

Comment: the sub-domain part isn't working, its in the question...

Comment: As in https://meta.discourse.org/t/how-do-you-go-on-configuring-another-sub-domain-with-the-nginx-instance-inside-the-docker/16846/16, can you try and use  `proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8002;` (instead of localhost)

Comment: Is see in http://blog.manugarri.com/how-to-easily-set-up-subdomain-routing-in-nginx/ that both `X-Real-IP` and `X-Forwarded-For` points to the same remote url. Although https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy/issues/130#issue-63797536 is a good read/to be tested: https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy would generate the right parameters for you.

Answer (score 3):

I have similar problems. Also I often need to add and remove containers, so I don't whant to edit nginx conf everytime. My solution was using jwilder/nginx-proxy.

then you just start containers with exposed port (`--expose 80`, not `-p 80:80`) and add env variables:

```
-e VIRTUAL_HOST=foo.bar.com
```

Don't forget to transfer with your main nginx traffic with right headers:

```
server {
    listen       80;# default_server;
    #send all subdomains to nginx-proxy
    server_name  *.bar.com;

    #proxy to docker nginx reverse proxy
    location / {
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr; #for some reason nginx 
        proxy_set_header   Host      $http_host;   #doesn't pass these by default
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:5100;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using jwilder/nginx-proxy haha, it's a great container

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `nginx-proxy` project (https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy). I wrote a tutorial in my blog which demonstrates exactly what you want to achieve using it: https://blog.florianlopes.io/host-multiple-websites-on-single-host-docker

This tool automatically forwards requests to the appropriate container (based on subdomain via the `VIRTUAL_HOST` container environment variable).

For example, if you want to access your container through test1.example.com, simply set the `VIRTUAL_HOST` container environment variable to `test1.example.com`.