# Subdomain single-tenancy - database per tenant vs container per tenant

Tags: database, docker, nginx, architecture, multi-tenant

It's an **accounting app**, accessed via subdomains (client names).

I did a lot of research and I can't decide which approach to use...

I am leaning towards `Approach 1 - Database per tenant`, but don't know what I don't know...

## Approach 1 - Database per tenant

Every time a new client is added, a script will be used to create the database for him.

Example:

```
client1.domain.com > client1_database
client2.domain.com > client2_database
```

There will be a single database connection pool, and the backend middleware will switch between databases for each API request based on the subdomain or payload in JWT token (to avoid the reverse-proxy shenanigans).

The web server will use a reverse-proxy to forward port 80 to port 3000 for the API.

**Concerns:**

- Will I run into a hardware or pool connection bottleneck if there are a lot of clients?
- Will the constant switching kill performance?
- Updates to database schemas will be tedious?

## Approach 2 - Container per tenant

Every tenant will live in it's own Docker container, with it's own database volume.

Example:

```
client1.domain.com > client1_container
client2.domain.com > client2_container
```

While being a cleaner solution, this will require orchestrating containers.

Everyone recommended using [nginx-proxy](https://github.com/nginx-proxy/nginx-proxy) for mapping subdomains to containers (basically writes nginx configs for each one).

**Concerns:**

- Will all these containers hog resources?
- Code updates seem like a problem because it will require constant container orchestration?
- Database schema updates may suck even more?

## Bonus approach - Multi-tenancy

I don't think using this for an accounting app is advisable (from what I've researched).

It will be an incredible mess having a shared database for everyone and differentiating data access with a clientId.

Also, not sure about the performance having a ton of rows.

## Resources

[Multi tenancy or multi instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34493998/multi-tenancy-or-multi-instance)
[Saas: Single-instance vs Multi-instance vs Single-tenant vs Multi-tenant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54892681/saas-single-instance-vs-multi-instance-vs-single-tenant-vs-multi-tenant)
[Route traffic to a docker container based on subdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24527485/route-traffic-to-a-docker-container-based-on-subdomain)
[Proxying Docker Containers as Subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36184343/proxying-docker-containers-as-subdomains)
[Docker run on sub domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33586062/docker-run-on-sub-domains)
[Does queries per second in MySql really matter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40827565/does-queries-per-second-in-mysql-really-matter)
[Multi-tenancy: Individual database per tenant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25369077/multi-tenancy-individual-database-per-tenant)
[To Multi-Tenant, or Not To Multi-tenant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596755/to-multi-tenant-or-not-to-multi-tenant)

Comment: I would go with Multi-Tenancy myself.  "It will be an incredible mess having a shared database for everyone and differentiating data access with a clientId."  Tying client identity into SQL queries is arguably a good thing anyway.   I would say this mess would be significantly less  incredible then the mess of trying to create distinct database servers, or even distinct databases.  Schemas are strictly defined.  If you normalize your data well, it shouldn't be confusing to access. As fro the performance, when you need to, you can do multi-tennant multi-dbserver sharding.

Comment: @erik258 Thank you so much for the reply. I will sketch a multi-tenant architecture, as I haven't truly considered it. I too can see how it might end up being "simpler" than handling hundreds of databases, or drowning in docker configs. Do you have any gotchas for multi-tenancy I should be aware of?

Comment: Just keep data ownership in mind and make identity and access control a part of the query conditions, and if you have a good normalized schema it should come together really well.